# Vb Script - Sorting the highest

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a simple program in VB script to sort the highest. There are two version of program, the first one is working but the second one where I enter values for array in run time is not working.

Could anyone help me in fixing this.

**version#1:**

```
dim arr(5)
arr(0)= 25
arr(1)= 12
arr(2)= 30
arr(3)= 45
arr(4)= 10
arr(5)=  5
dim Buffer
Buffer = 0
dim i

for i=0 to 5
  if arr(i) > Buffer Then Buffer = arr(i)
Next

Msgbox "The Highest is" &Buffer
```

**Version 2** (This one doesn't work with the data - (25,12,30,45,10,5) - It says 5 as highest one.

```
dim arr(5)
dim j
for j=0 to 5
  arr(j)=inputbox("Enter Data")
Next

dim Buffer
Buffer = 0
dim i

for i=0 to 5
  if arr(i) > Buffer Then Buffer = arr(i)
Next

Msgbox "The Highest is" &Buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem: While you compare numbers in your first sample, you compare strings (from the InputBox()) in your second. "5" is (alphabetically) greater than "49999999". Use CInt() or CLng() to convert the string input into numbers.